# Canon printer constantly forgets wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, connection

My Canon PIXMA MX522 wireless printer constantly needs to be reconnected to my wireless network. Pretty much every single day I have to climb under my desk, hold down the router connection button, and then wait for my printer to re-connect to the network.

I've set the printer up to use a static IP, but that hasn't helped at all.

This is driving me crazy. Can anyone offer a suggestion as to how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: How far away is the printer from the router? Have you tried restarting the wireless router? Do any of your other wireless devices drop out?

Comment: It's about 5 feet away, in the same room. Other devices don't have any issue.